# Organic Groups cannot set Membership type when i add a user to a group

Tags: organic-groups

I am using [OG 2.7](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), I have just created a new membership type. however when I go to add a user to a group content type, it is not letting me choose what membership type to use. It only shows the user auto-complete, a check-box to choose the role and the default membership type fields.
Why can it be that I cannot see the membership type selector??
Is there any place in configuration where it can be enable or disabled?
What could I be missing here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but did you manage to find a solution?